# Равная высота ячеек таблицы HTML

Tags: html, css

Как задать одинаковую высоту ячеек в таблице HTML? Есть растянутая по размеру экрана таблица с 4-мя ячейками, как задать им одинаковую высоту (как table-layout:fixed;, только применимо к высоте).

Comment: только джаваскриптом. достаешь, например, ширину ячейки и присваиваешь ее значение высоте ячейки

Answer (score 1):

А зачем, собственно таблица?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  padding: .5em;
}

section {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  padding: .5em;
  float: left;
}

div {
  border: 1px dotted green;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<section><div>1</div></section>
<section><div>2</div></section>
<section><div>3</div></section>
<section><div>4</div></section>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
td {
    height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Мне не нужен фиксированный размер, шаблон резиновый, необходимо растягивать шаблон в высоту, но выравнивание получается по содержимому.

Answer (score 0):

Если 4 ячеек и на всю высоту, в сумме, то можно:

```
<td>
    height:25%;
    width:25%; //на всякий случай
</td>
```

Comment: Не подойдет, так как выставляется margin в определенное кол-во пикселей, а так же border-spacing. В итоге мы можем получить таблицу больше, чем 100% (с учетом margin и padding). К тому же, выше есть шапка в 20px. Мне просто нужно занять оставшееся пространство ячейками (2 по 2). С шириной это получилось (отнюдь не указанием ширины в процентах или фиксированным значением).